# How can I make routes from a Rails 3 engine available to the host application?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, url-routing, rails-routing, rails-engines

I have a Rails 3 application with several engines containing additional functionality. Each engine is a separate service that customers can purchase access to.

I am, however, having a problem with routes from the engines that aren't readily available to the controllers and views.

controller:

```
class ClassroomsController < ApplicationController
  ..
  respond_to :html

  def index
    respond_with(@classrooms = @company.classrooms.all)
  end

  def new
     respond_with(@classroom = @company.classrooms.build)
  end

  ..
end
```

`app/views/classrooms/new.html.haml`:

```
= form_for @classroom do |f|
  ..
  f.submit
```

`config/routes.rb` in engine:

```
MyEngineName::Engine.routes.draw do
  resources :classrooms
end
```

`config/routes.rb` in app:

```
Seabed::Application.routes.draw do
  mount MyEngineName::Engine => '/engine'
  ...
end
```

`lib/my_engine_name.rb` in engine:

```
module MyEngineName
  class Engine < ::Rails::Engine
  end
end
```

attempting to go to `/classrooms/new` results in

```
NoMethodError in Classrooms#new

Showing app/views/classrooms/_form.html.haml where line #1 raised:
  undefined method `hash_for_classrooms_path' for #<Module:0x00000104cff0f8>
```

and attempting to call `classrooms_path` from any other view results in the same error.
I can, however, call `MyEngineName::Engine.routes.url_helpers.classrooms_path` and get it working. I'm thinking I might have defined the routes wrong, but can't find another way that works.

Tried running the app with both Passenger (standalone and Apache module) and WEBrick (rails server). Using latest Rails from Git (`7c920631ec3b314cfaa3a60d265de40cba3e8135`).

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Change `config.routes` in your engine to:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do  # NOT MyEngineName::Engine.routes.draw
  resources :classrooms
end
```

The way you have it, the routes are only available in the `MyEngineName::Engine` namespace and not in the rest of the host rails application.

There used to be a blog post with more info, but unfortunately it is no longer available:

- http://blog.loopedstrange.com/modest-rubyist-archive/rails-3-plugins-part2-writing-an-engine

Comment: Doing that, removing the mount-call in my app-routes, and scoping in engine-routes (`scope '/engine' do`) and everything works. Thanks a lot :)

Comment: Cool, thanks for the info on the other steps needed to get the Engine routes working.

Comment: For Rails 3.1 and later, remove the `map` parameter to the block (just remove the entire `|map|` part).

Comment: What if I have a catch-all route at the bottom of my main app? How do I ensure these engine's routes are not just appended to the bottom of the host app's routes?

Comment: @Jwan622 Not sure about that. There may be some useful info in this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7040520/457819

Comment: Unfortunately, the blog post link seems to be dead.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know. Couldn't find a new URL for the blog post. Let me know if you find one. Added a note to the answer to indicate the link was down.

Answer (score 26):

I had the same problem, and found this in the [documentation](http://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/Rails/Engine.html):

Since you can now mount an engine inside application’s routes, you do not have direct access to Engine‘s url_helpers inside Application. When you mount an engine in an application’s routes, a special helper is created to allow you to do that. Consider such a scenario:

```
# config/routes.rb
MyApplication::Application.routes.draw do
  mount MyEngine::Engine => "/my_engine", :as => "my_engine"
  get "/foo" => "foo#index"
end
```

Now, you can use the my_engine helper inside your application:

```
class FooController < ApplicationController
  def index
    my_engine.root_url #=> /my_engine/
  end
end
```

Comment: for code inside the Engine, do you need to prepend routes to its own controllers with the engine's name as well? Or can you just use `classrooms_path` from inside the Engine?

Comment: Jwan622, for the own routes you can use helpers without any prefixes.

Answer (score 2):

For me also help to add

```
require 'engine' if defined?(Rails)
```

to my main gem file (lib/.rb).

Good example - https://github.com/mankind/Rails-3-engine-example/blob/master/lib/dummy.rb