# How to get host routes from a rails engine?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-engines

I have a rails engine that has routes, views, models and controllers plugged into the host application.

I mount the engine in host routes like so:

```
mount HelpCenter::Engine, at: "/help_center"
```

When I go to a view provided by the engine (it is using a layout from the host), it is getting errors when it tries to resolve routes from the navigation bar (host routes).

How do I provide routes from the host into the engine?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use

```
main_app.route_from_my_host_application
```

This way engine will find for the path in your host routes

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the answer in [How can I make routes from a Rails 3 engine available to the host application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4361050/how-can-i-make-routes-from-a-rails-3-engine-available-to-the-host-application)

> Change config.routes in your engine to:
>
> ```
> Rails.application.routes.draw do  # NOT MyEngineName::Engine.routes.draw
>   resources :classrooms
> end
> ```

Comment: Thanks for the link, however this solution is not going to scale across multiple apps.

Comment: How do I use the url helpers from the rails engine? where do I define what the host is so I don't get this error: `Missing host to link to! Please provide the :host parameter, set default_url_options[:host], or set :only_path to true`